# Do liquid consonants ever become dental fricatives?

Tags: phonology, sound-change, laterals, rhotics, dental-fricative

Is a sound change from /l/ or /r/ to a voiced dental fricative attested in any languages?

(Furthermore is there some database for searching sound changes?)

Comment: it's not a scholarly database, but Index Diachronica is a tool for checking this sort of thing developed for conlangers. It does come with some caveats though as it's drawn from sources that don't always use standard transcriptions, so things may not always appear as IPA, and also that in some instances it may accept certain hypotheses that are more uncertain than communis opinio: https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/

Comment: a quick look there shows L Lʲ → {ð,j} ʒ / \_”V for Proto-Siouan to Proto-Dhegiha; L → θ / \_”V and Lʲ → {θ,n} / \_V[+nas -stress] and Lʲ → ð / \_V[+nas -stress] and pr sr tʲr kr → bð sts ʃd ɡð and r → ð / x\_ for Proto-Dhegiha to Omaha-Ponca; l → {r,ð} for Proto-Algonquian to Woods Cree; and kl → ð and {r,r̥} → ð for North Tai to Dioi

Comment: Not a sound change, but the so-called ‘soft d’ in Danish – phonemically /ð/, phonetically something like [ð̠˕ˠ] – is often perceived as [l] by non-Danes, much to the confusion of Danes who can see no acoustic similarity at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's even less relevant here, but that sort of contrary perception is seen between Mandarin "r" /ʐ/ which is perceived by English-speakers as the same as /ɹ/, which Mandarin speakers then perceive as the same as their /l/ (which is perceived by English-speakers as /l/)

Comment: @Tristan Definitely getting off-topic now, but I don’t think that’s actually true currently, or at least only in part. Speakers of Modern Standard Mandarin who have retroflex /ʐ/ (so especially northern speakers) will generally equate English /r/ with Mandarin /ʐ/, not /l/. Speakers who don’t have retroflexes (so especially southern speakers) are more likely to perceive it as /l/. In loan words, there’s an established convention to use /l/, but that’s due to Cantonese in large part; without that convention, I doubt /l/ would be used for English loans in MSM.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ah, I must have misunderstood the stuff I was reading as being based on Mandarin-speakers' perceptions rather than them porting Cantonese perceptions

Answer (score -1):

One of the most famous cases is Polish, where old **[r]** first got palatalized before the front vowels into [rʲ] and then lost the palatalization and changed its quality to **[ʐ]**, graphically `<rz>`, e.g. Proto-Slavic **rěčь* > Polish *[rzecz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rzecz#Polish)* [ʐɛt͡ʂ] “thing, matter, action, deed”, one of the most often used Polish words, as in *Rzeczpospolita* [ʐɛt͡ʂ.pɔˈspɔ.li.ta] “(formal) Poland (the Polish state)”, from *rzecz* (“thing”) +‎ *pospolita* (“common”), calque of Latin *rēspūblica* (“public affair”).

See “Loss of palatalization in certain environments” section of this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Polish_language#Phonetic_processes_from_Proto-Slavic) (*History of Polish language > Phonetic processes from Proto-Slavic*).

Comment: But [ʐ] isn’t a dental fricative..?